# Foreground of textblock doesn't work when use custom url font in wpf

Tags: wpf, fonts

I'm using custom url font file in wpf (MS Mincho font) to display japanese characters

Here are my code:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBlockDisplayResource" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="./fonts/#MS Mincho"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>


<TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="30" Foreground="Black"
                               Style="{DynamicResource TextBlockDisplayResource}" 
                               Text="This is black color"></TextBlock>
```

I have folder in solution "**fonts/MS mincho.ttf**"

In Visual studio.. I saw the color result of textblock is black. But when i build, the color is lightblue. even i set foreground=black.

I don't know where i was wrong.

When i try to change set url for **fontfamily**

```
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,/fonts/#MS Mincho"/>
```

The error is the same

Please let's me know.

Thanks.